# Rails 4 update Type when migrating to Single Table Inheritance

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, single-table-inheritance

Rails 4.0.4, Ruby 2.1.2

I want to use STI like so:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
Admin < User
```

But currently I have:

```
User < ActiveRecord::Base
Info < ActiveRecord::Base
```

So I changed my models, and then start writing my migration. In my migration, I first add a column to allow STI:

```
add_column :users, :type, :string
```

Then I want to update the Users currently in the database to be Admin

```
# Place I'm currently stuck
```

Then I move all my Info records into the Users table

```
Info.all.each { |info| User.create(name: info.name, email: info.email) }
```

Everything seems to work except turning the previous Users into Admins. Here are some things I've tried:

```
# Seems to work, but doesn't actually save type value
User.each do |user|
  user.becomes!(Admin)
  user.save! # evaluates to true, doesn't have any errors
end

# Seems to work, but doesn't actually save type value
# I've also tried a combo of this one and the above one
User.each do |user|
  user.type = "Admin"
  user.save! # evaluates to true, doesn't have any errors
end

User.each do |user|
  user = user.becomes!(Admin)
  user.save! # evaluates to true, doesn't have any errors
end

# Seems to work, but doesn't actually save type value
User.each do |user|
  user.update_attributes(type: "Admin")
end
```

Each time the local user variables seems to have the correct type ("Admin"), along with save evaluating to true, but when I check `Admin.count` or check Users type value, it is always nil. I know you're not supposed to change them, but this is just to migrate the data over to STI and then I'll be able to start creating Users or Admin with the proper class.

At the very least I think Rails should raise an error, set an error or somehow let the developer know it's failing the save calls.

Comment: Notice that the in-memory objects will still be of the previous Class. Try reloading the objects, and you should see the new Class on those Users.

Comment: I have, by performing `User.where(...)` and `Admin.all` and get the same results as I did before the updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had more rows in the database User.each would become quite slow as it makes an SQL call for each user.

Generally you could use `User.update_all(field: value)` to do this in one SQL call but there is another reason to avoid this: if the `User` model is later removed the migration will no longer run.

One way to update all rows at once without referencing the model is to use raw SQL in the migration:

```
def up
  execute "UPDATE users SET type = 'Admin' WHERE type IS NULL"
end
```

Comment: Definitely agree this would be much better than instantiating all those objects

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that while `update_attributes` doesn't work for type (I haven't researched why yet), `update_column` does work.

So the migration simply becomes:

```
User.each do |user|
  user.update_columns(type: "Admin")
end
```

The reason this works and other updates don't can probably be traced back to either callbacks or validations not being run. I have no callbacks that would prevent it, but maybe there are default Rails ones for `type`

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_columns